# Determining Noise Filter Requirements

Tags: audio, filter, noise

Some electronic equipment designs are designed to clearly specified noise standards, so filter design is carried out to attain those specs. However, say you were designing a piece of DC-powered pro-audio equipment (could be anything though), where there aren't any clearly defined standards, and you wanted to filter the DC power supply coming into a linear regulator, which powers all of the analog electronics. How would you go about determining what noise amplitude to aim for at the output, over what frequency range?

Comment: How to design a specification?

Answer (score 3):

Figure out how much audio noise you can tolerate on the output, and work back through the PSRR of the amp and the parasitic paths to come up with a ripple spec on the power supply.

That's easy to say and not necessarily easy to do.  Simulation can help, but you may need a couple of iterations of PCB layout and test to dial it in.  Running a PSRR sweep on the audio path portion in the lab will be very helpful.

Comment: Good info, by running a PSRR sweep, do you mean inject a sine wave into the regulator input during normal operation and measure the residual ripple at the output?

Comment: So assuming you have some idea of what level of audio noise is acceptable, I was suggesting injecting sinusoidal noise on the power supply rails of the audio circuitry to see what the rejection ratio is from supply to audio out over frequency.  Then you can use that to set a target for the output of your regulator.  Once you have that, you can design your regulator or regulator and filter to meet the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of 60/120Hz ripple setting the Signal Noise Ratio at 85 dB.
The opamps have default 80dB PSRR. There is 40db total gain. The ripple into the VDD pin of each opamp is 10 milliVolts.

Is 85dB adequate for you? The input level is 0.1 voltPP.

[image]

I used the Master Settings (one of top left buttons) and selected the Power Chain Explorer to edit the default PSRR from 80dB to 100dB. The SNR remains
84.5dB, which tells us the PSRR is not (now) the problem.

Here is the thermal noise plot.

[image]

Notice the first OPAMP, with noise density of 4 nanoVolts/rtHz (1Kohm equivalent), and the Rg (resistor from -pin to GND) with value of 10Kohm, are now setting the SNR.